# Got error (timeout of 2000ms exceeded) while testing async function in a service

Tags: angular, jasmine, mocha.js, sinon

I have a service with following details:

```
class MyService {
   myFunction(param){
        return Observable.create(obs => {
             callsDBfunc(param, (err, res) => {
                  if(err)
                      obs.error(err);
                  else
                      obs.next(res);
             });
        });
   }
}
```

When i am trying to test it i am getting an error:

> Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being
>   called in this test.

My test is as below:

```
it('test signup()', (done) => {
     authService = new AuthService();
     let credentials = {username: '1234', password: '1234'};
     let spyVMAddUser = spy(VM_Users_AddUser, 'call');
     authService.signup(credentials).subscribe(data => {
         expect(data).to.eql(credentials);
         done();
     });
     assert.calledOnce(spyVMAddUser);
     spyVMAddUser.restore();
});
```

I tried (1) converting observale into Promise and then chaining done to the end like .then(done,done). (2) tried putting setTimeOut(20000) getting the same error.

(3) I even tried to stub the method rather than spy with following code and got the same error.

```
stub(VM_Users_AddUser, 'call').withArgs(credentials).returns(credentials);
```

Please help. I am trying to resolve this error for past 2-3 days.

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue. I was not calling function with appro callback. When i called stub with yieldsAaync(null, callbackSpy) it worked.